# Is it advisable to avoid bulkification in a trigger on attachment object?

Tags: trigger, bulkification

I'm required to change the title of each attachment on an upload to the name of the expense item. I have written a bulkified code

```
trigger ExpenseProof on Attachment (before insert) {

    set<id> itemids = new set<id>();
    for(attachment att:trigger.new){
        if(att.parentid.getSobjectType() == Expense_Item__c.sObjectType){
        itemids.add(att.ParentId);
     }
    }

   Map<Id,expense_item__c> itemMap = new Map<Id, expense_item__c>([select name from expense_item__c where id in :itemids]);

    for(attachment att:trigger.new)
    {
     if((att.parentid.getSobjectType() == Expense_Item__c.sObjectType) && itemMap.containsKey(att.ParentId))
            att.Name= itemmap.get(att.ParentId).name;
    }
}
```

and a non-bulkified code

```
    trigger ExpenseProof on Attachment (before insert) {

    for(attachment att:Trigger.new)
    {
        if(att.parentid.getSobjectType() == Expense_Item__c.sObjectType)
        {
            att.Name= [select name from expense_item__c where id =:att.ParentId].name;
        }
    }
}
```

Shall I ignore the bulkified one as I don't foresee a scenario where more than 200 attachments are going to be uploaded at once?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even if you are 100% sure that there is no possibility you will not have 200 attachments to modify, you also have to think that other code might execute in the same execution context and if the code you are creating is not efficient, it might impact the code that would have succeeded if the resources used by your code were lower.

So always optimise your code to run with the lowest resource possible.

Comment: Why the trivial edit?

Comment: It didn't like how I was using "that" word twice in such a short space.

Answer (score 6):

There is no Harm in adding this bulkification.  NEVER say never....you could find the need to do a mass upload of attachments in the future, or another admin could do it as well.

ESPECIALLY since you already have the code written, go with the bulkified.  In my opinion, I'd rather have something in place that I might never need, but be all set in the off chance that I do need it.....No risk in being overprepared for all scenarios.

If you think about it, what does ***NOT*** putting in the bulkified code save you?

Comment: Merry Christmas, didn't understand "If you think about it, what does NOT putting in the bulkified code save you?"

Comment: I just mean that what do you gain by putting in the non bulkified code.  Just that it's not like there is any gain or benefit to not adding the bulkified code.

Comment: Ok, I get it, thought there's some mistake with my bulkified code which I should correct

Comment: @Bennie *Always* prefer bulkified code. Just because you can't foresee a situation where more than a handful of records could exist in a trigger doesn't mean you won't later have a situation where you will such a feature. In fact, it's almost guaranteed to happen at some point. You have to consider all possibilities, and one such possibility is that someone will need this trigger to work with bulk uploads.

Comment: @Bennie. The 1st project I ever worked on everything was supposed to be entered via the UI. The next thing we knew, the client was doing bulk uploads and things began to break because it didn't follow the formatting the UI provided. I had to re-write my trigger to accommodate that. Always be prepared for those types of scenarios.

Comment: Totally agree with fox and progdev.  Great points guys.